# Android telegram App --> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetFieldID called with pending exception 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'

Tags: android

Im trying to build an own Telegram app for android via source but after generating native file and debug it. in line System.loadLibrary() it stop with the following error

```
03-14 16:07:46.225 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetFieldID called with pending exception 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException' thrown in unknown throw location
03-14 16:07:46.225 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to GetFieldID
03-14 16:07:46.225 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     from java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String)
03-14 16:07:46.225 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
03-14 16:07:46.225 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x72c85000 self=0xb8caced0
03-14 16:07:46.225 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | sysTid=18870 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f8bbec
03-14 16:07:46.225 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | state=R schedstat=( 774073910 85715465 415 ) utm=72 stm=5 core=2 HZ=100
03-14 16:07:46.225 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | stack=0xbe041000-0xbe043000 stackSize=8MB
03-14 16:07:46.225 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
03-14 16:07:46.225 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #00 pc 0000484c  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
03-14 16:07:46.225 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #01 pc 00003031  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
03-14 16:07:46.225 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #02 pc 00243b8b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*, BacktraceMap*)+70)
03-14 16:07:46.225 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #03 pc 002282af  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, BacktraceMap*) const+154)
03-14 16:07:46.225 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #04 pc 000b00dd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+584)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #05 pc 000b0825  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+60)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #06 pc 000b3967  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::ScopedCheck(_JNIEnv*, int, char const*)+1286)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #07 pc 000b5bb3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::GetFieldID(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, char const*, char const*)+26)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #08 pc 000c61c8  /data/app/org.melegram.messenger-1/lib/arm/libtmessages.19.so (sqliteOnJNILoad+64)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #09 pc 000c5c18  /data/app/org.melegram.messenger-1/lib/arm/libtmessages.19.so (JNI_OnLoad+84)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #10 pc 001d2c41  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::LoadNativeLibrary(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, art::Handle, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >*)+1584)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #11 pc 001f7de5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime_nativeLoad(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jstring*, _jobject*, _jstring*)+528)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #12 pc 000797dd  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_java_lang_Runtime_nativeLoad__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_ClassLoader_2Ljava_lang_String_2+152)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native method)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.Runtime.doLoad(Runtime.java:428)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   - locked  (a java.lang.Runtime)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:369)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at org.melegram.messenger.NativeLoader.initNativeLibs(NativeLoader.java:176)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   - locked  (a java.lang.Class)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at org.melegram.messenger.ApplicationLoader.onCreate(ApplicationLoader.java:267)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4659)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:156)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
03-14 16:07:46.226 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] 
03-14 16:07:46.286 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295] Runtime aborting...
03-14 16:07:46.286 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295] Aborting thread:
03-14 16:07:46.286 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
03-14 16:07:46.286 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x72c85000 self=0xb8caced0
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   | sysTid=18870 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f8bbec
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   | state=R schedstat=( 809097712 85715465 416 ) utm=74 stm=6 core=2 HZ=100
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   | stack=0xbe041000-0xbe043000 stackSize=8MB
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   native: #00 pc 0000484c  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   native: #01 pc 00003031  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   native: #02 pc 00243b8b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*, BacktraceMap*)+70)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   native: #03 pc 002282af  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, BacktraceMap*) const+154)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   native: #04 pc 0021825d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::DumpThread(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, art::Thread*)+24)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   native: #05 pc 0021850d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream >&)+436)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   native: #06 pc 002186e1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+72)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   native: #07 pc 000a65bb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1322)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   native: #08 pc 000b02cb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1078)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   native: #09 pc 000b0825  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+60)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   native: #10 pc 000b3967  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::ScopedCheck(_JNIEnv*, int, char const*)+1286)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   native: #11 pc 000b5bb3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::GetFieldID(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, char const*, char const*)+26)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   native: #12 pc 000c61c8  /data/app/org.melegram.messenger-1/lib/arm/libtmessages.19.so (sqliteOnJNILoad+64)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   native: #13 pc 000c5c18  /data/app/org.melegram.messenger-1/lib/arm/libtmessages.19.so (JNI_OnLoad+84)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   native: #14 pc 001d2c41  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::LoadNativeLibrary(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, art::Handle, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >*)+1584)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   native: #15 pc 001f7de5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime_nativeLoad(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jstring*, _jobject*, _jstring*)+528)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   native: #16 pc 000797dd  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_java_lang_Runtime_nativeLoad__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_ClassLoader_2Ljava_lang_String_2+152)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native method)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at java.lang.Runtime.doLoad(Runtime.java:428)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   - locked  (a java.lang.Runtime)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:369)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at org.melegram.messenger.NativeLoader.initNativeLibs(NativeLoader.java:176)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   - locked  (a java.lang.Class)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at org.melegram.messenger.ApplicationLoader.onCreate(ApplicationLoader.java:267)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4659)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:156)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295] Pending exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException thrown by 'unknown throw location'
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.telegram.SQLite.SQLitePreparedStatement" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/org.melegram.messenger-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.melegram.messenger-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:511)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:469)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String) (Runtime.java:-2)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.doLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Runtime.java:428)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at void java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Runtime.java:369)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at void java.lang.System.loadLibrary(java.lang.String) (System.java:988)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at void org.melegram.messenger.NativeLoader.initNativeLibs(android.content.Context) (NativeLoader.java:176)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at void org.melegram.messenger.ApplicationLoader.onCreate() (ApplicationLoader.java:267)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at void android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(android.app.Application) (Instrumentation.java:1012)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:4659)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:156)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1412)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:211)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:5371)
03-14 16:07:46.287 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[], boolean) (Method.java:-2)
03-14 16:07:46.288 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:372)
03-14 16:07:46.288 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:945)
03-14 16:07:46.288 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:740)
03-14 16:07:46.288 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
03-14 16:07:46.288 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:295] 
03-14 16:07:46.288 18870-18870/org.melegram.messenger A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 18870 (egram.messenger)
```

How can i fix this issue? was this issue related to art or dalvik?

My Android Studio version 1.5.1
target test machine android 5.1.1

Comment: The class `org.telegram.SQLite.SQLitePreparedStatement` couldn't be found in your app. You need to make sure that you are building with all the necessary libraries, and you didn't change or obfuscate any Java names that are referenced from native code.

Comment: I don't change any thing just telegram->melegram because my phone has telegram and conflict with it

Comment: @Khalil What was the solution?

Comment: When i change package name to melegram some of files not changed and  remained in telegram name i  searched all file 'org.telegram.messenger' and change to melegram and worked like charm. with android studio search all of files In particular native code files.